# How does the memory layout of a struct of 2 floats differ from an array float[2][1]?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, arduino, samd51

I can successfully cast a pointer to a struct of 2 floats to a void pointer (used to discard incompatible pointer types warning), and then cast that to a float array and use that normally, however it doesn't seem to work in reverse with `memcpy()`.

Say I have the following

```
struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} s;

float f[2][1] = {{6}, {3}};
```

I notice that if I use `memcpy()` to copy `f` to `s`

```
memcpy(&s, f, sizeof(f));
```

`f[0][0]` and `f[1][0]` are both 0. Intuitively I would expect it to do the same as

```
s.x = f[0][0];
s.y = f[1][0];
```

Why does this not work?

EDIT: I have been asked for more complete code:

```
void add(const float a[2][1], float b, float dest[2][1])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            dest[i][j] = a[i][j] + b;
        }
    }
}

void predict(struct State *x, float u)
{
    float buffer[2][1];
    add(x, u, buffer); // Incompatible pointer types, but it works.
    x->x = buffer[0][0];
    x->y = buffer[1][0];
    //memcpy(x, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think since you have a matrix you need to loop through it an then use memcpy

Comment: @Tom OP has now edited - originally, the question stated that the call was an attempt to copy `s` to `f`.

Comment: I edited the post after realising my mistake, unless you are seeing the new version? I assume destination is first because the prototype's first argument is void*, and the second is const void*.

Comment: Just to be sure there isn't something weird going on with the compiler, can you tell us what the values are for `sizeof(s)` and `sizeof(f)`? They should be the same, I think, but there may be a memory overflow issue if they're not.

Comment: It's undefined behavior. But it works fine here: https://ideone.com/CU2vqn

Comment: @SupportUkraine OP doesn't say what values are placed in the `s` members but that the call appears to overwrite the `f` data. This is why I would like to see what the sizes are.

Comment: What machine are you running this code on and what compiler are you using?

Comment: @AdrianMole hmmm.... true. I kind of missed that. That's why OP should post a complete program instead of describing the code :-( Anyway, there is no way the memcpy can overwrite `f`. Unless "undefined behavior" really means: Do stupid things ;-)

Comment: This is being compiled for an ATSAMD51 microcontroller using the Arduino environment. Interestingly and most confusingly the code works in c++ but not in c.

Comment: @TheRedstoneHive Post your **complete** program that has the described behavior so that we can copy it and execute on our own system

Comment: A `struct` can have padding bytes, arrays don`t have padding bytes.

Comment: So you say that `buffer` is all zero when using `memcpy` !? How do you know? Are you using a debugger to show it? Then you can't trust the values as `memcpy`. Do a simple print instead.

Comment: Undefined behavior is not confined to the statement or expression that causes it.  Fix your strict-aliasing violation, and see whether your program still misbehaves.

Comment: `//memcpy(x, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // doesn't work` What exactly doesn't work? What do you see? What do you expect to see?

Comment: I'm just printing the values with Serial.print. I wish I had a debugger, but those are expensive.

Answer (score 3):

> How does the memory layout of a struct of 2 floats differ from an array float[2][1]?

The array layout is

```
 ---------------
| float | float |
 ---------------
```

The struct layout is

```
 -----------------------------------
| float | padding | float | padding |
 -----------------------------------
```

How big the padding fields are in bytes depends on the compiler.

The padding may be zero bytes (and typically will be zero bytes) in which case the layout is the same.

But from a standard point of view your code has undefined behavior because the array and the struct may have different size.

Comment: Can there be padding at the start of a `struct`?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No, padding is **not** allowed before first member. In other words - padding is **only** allowed after members

Comment: It is undefined behaviour because of the strict aliasing rules, not because the sizes might be different.

Comment: If there was padding then wouldn't this assert fail?
static_assert(sizeof(struct State) == 2 * sizeof(float), "sizeof State");
Or does padding not increase the size of the struct (I thought it did)

Comment: @TheRedstoneHive Yes, it would. When padding is present the size increase. But we can't really help your further. You don't post code that shows the bug. Just just tells something happens without any code. We can't help further.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit `memcpy` between objects of different types is not a violation of strict aliasing. As long as the number of bytes copied isn't more than the size of source and destination it's fine. The problem comes when using the destination after the copy. For OPs code the value of struct member `y` is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

> I can successfully cast a pointer to a struct of 2 floats to a void pointer (used to discard incompatible pointer types warning), and then cast that to a float array and use that normally,

Interposing an extra cast may silence the warning, but that does not mean the issue your compiler was warning about is solved.  You've basically told your compiler "don't bother me, I know what I'm doing", even though you *do not* know what you are doing in this regard (else you would not need to pose the present question).

Since you cannot cast to an array type, I presume you mean that you cast to a *pointer to* an array.  In other words,

```
// probably ...
float (*ap)[1] = (float (*)[1]) s;

// or maybe ...
float (*ap)[2][1] = (float (*)[2][1]) s;
```

If you then access the struct via the resulting array pointer, you violate the strict aliasing rule, and thereby obtain **undefined behavior**.  Even if the layout of the struct is exactly the same as the layout of an array of two `float`.  That may appear to work as you expect, but that doesn't mean it's ok, nor that it is without adverse effect.

> however it doesn't seem to work in reverse with memcpy().

In general, there's no particular reason why it should, though the seeming success of your experiment with casting might give you reason to think so.  That's because the language does not answer the title question,

> How does the memory layout of a struct of 2 floats differ from an array float[2][1]?

, with any specificity.  The members of a struct are required to be arranged in memory in the order they are declared (disregarding bitfields for our purposes), and the first member must appear at the beginning of the struct.  As far as C is concerned, however, there may be arbitrary padding after any member or members.  On the other hand, the elements of an array are consecutive in memory, and there is no trailing padding, either.

HOWEVER, if the representation of your struct type happens to be the same as that of an array of two `float`, then `memcpy()` is a valid way to copy the contents of such an array into the struct.

For example, the SYSV x86_64 ABI used by 64-bit x86_64 Linux does specify that your struct will be laid out the same as an array of two `float`.  On my 64-bit Linux system, this program ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    float arr[2][1] = {{6}, {3}};
    printf("%f %f\n", arr[0][0], arr[1][0]);

    struct { float x, y; } s;
    memcpy(&s, arr, sizeof s);
    printf("%f %f\n", s.x, s.y);
}
```

... compiles fine and outputs exactly what I expect:

> ```
> jbolling@Lucky:~/tmp> ./example
> 6.000000 3.000000
> 6.000000 3.000000
> ```